# Insufficient privileges to complete the operation (Azure AD Issue)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I try to get all users from azure ad on behalf of user, I have my custom role, my question is what is the needed permission to add it to custom role to get all users from azure ad ?!

Comment: What delegated permissions (scopes) have you granted to the application? Does the user have rights to read users?

Answer (score 0):

- In custom directory role, there is no permission specifically to list users. There are permissions for Groups, Applications and ServicePrincipals but not Users. You can either assign built in Directory Role like User Admin role or Directory Reader role.
- You may  use below PS commands to assign directory reader role if there are many users who need this permission.

1. `$role1 = Get-AzureADDirectoryRole -ObjectId ID`
2. `Add-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember -ObjectId $role1.ObjectId -RefObjectId object_id_of_user`
3. `Get-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember -ObjectId $role1.ObjectId | Get-AzureADUser`